# How to tag background like Acrobat with Itext 7-dotnet?

Tags: c#, pdf, tags, itext, low-level

how is it possible to tag an element on an existing pdf like Adobe acrobat as background? It seems to be that Acrobat tags different as normal itext tagging. It seems to be that there tag direct the element and remove the coressponding tag from tag tree ([source](https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2017/07/25/accessible-pdfs-in-acrobat-dc-tagging-content-as-an-artifact.html)).

I can set the corresponding tag in tag tree to artifact, but i don`t know how i can can tag the linked original object?

```
tagTreePointer.MoveToKid(0);

        for (int kidIndex = tagTreePointer.GetKidsRoles().Count - 1; kidIndex >= 0; kidIndex--)
        {
            var kidsRole = tagTreePointer.GetStandardRoleOfKid(kidIndex);
            if (!kidsRole.Equals(PdfName.Span.GetValue(), StringComparison.Ordinal)) continue;

            tagTreePointer.MoveToKid(kidIndex);

            if (tagTreePointer.GetKidsRoles() is IList<string> kidsRoles && kidsRoles.Count == 1 && kidsRoles.FirstOrDefault() is string kidKidRole && kidKidRole.Equals(PdfName.MCR.GetValue(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // here i set the role of tag to artifcat but it is only the tag not the pdfobject
                tagTreePointer.SetRole(PdfName.Artifact.GetValue());
                if (tagTreePointer.GetContext().GetPointerStructElem(tagTreePointer) is PdfStructElem pdfStructElement)
                {
                    if (pdfStructElement.GetKids().FirstOrDefault() is PdfMcrNumber pdfMcrNumber)
                    {
                        var pageObject = pdfMcrNumber.GetPageObject();
                    }
                }
            }
```

If i set a new role to the parent tag then pac 3 say it is okay but if i remove the tag from tree then pac 3 says all elements from container are untagged.

Maybe anyone has an idea?

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: Can you attach the original PDF in question and adjust the code so that it's runnable against the PDF? Basically you can assign an explicit /Artifact role to a tag, or you can tag some content as Artifact in inline mode. Do I understand correctly that you want to exclude your content from the structure tree (tag tree)? It can be a bit difficult to achieve. Is there any reason, apart from cosmetic one, to hide the tag completely if PAC3 says all is fine?

Comment: @AlexeySubach It is more a cosmetic question. Adobe acrobat seems to be modify the content stream and remove the tag from the structure tree. So for general it seems to be there is no way to modifiy the "tagged" content object and modify they stream like acrobat. The original pdf comes from the microsoft excel exporter.

Comment: There is a way to modify your PDF to hide the content from the structure tree completely. It's just quite a complicated job to do (you have to locate your objects in content stream, and add the inline role wrapper around them, and also remove the tags from the structure tree), so I would advice against it.

Comment: @AlexeySubach I dont`t found a way to modfiy the content stream of an object (the examples of itext are often only the pdf creation and tag way and not the modifying way ;) )  When i have the mcid of the object then it should be possible to get the object so the question is how i can modify the content stream to add the role wrapper around them.

Comment: @AlexeySubach I found a hacky trick to set it. With the code above i can evaluate alle mcids of the artifacts and (with a little bit more code) the pageNumber where there are located. With these informations it is possible to load the correct byte array of the contentstream and convert them to a string. Then i can replace /P <<MCID {Number}>> with /Artifact <<MCID {Number}>> and write it back. This generic artifact tag seems to be allowed through the pdf reference.